# UWP/XAML editor on click

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

How or which control use for next

**Phone:  123456789**

Click on Phone or 123456789 open edit dialog.

Dialog must be customizable TextBox, ComboBox or many controls

Sample

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best I think would be here generic *Flyout*. Sample:

```xml
<Border Background="Transparent" Tapped="Border_Tapped">
    <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
        <Flyout Placement="Bottom">
            <TextBox Header="Enter text" Text="{x:Bind myText.Text, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </Flyout>
    </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
    <TextBlock x:Name="myText" Margin="50" Text="Sample text"/>
</Border>
```

Code behind:

```cs
private void Border_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e) =>
        FlyoutBase.GetAttachedFlyout(sender as FrameworkElement).ShowAt(sender as FrameworkElement);
```